# IBM NeuralSeek API Filter

Tags: python, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson

How can I filter from a specific watson discovery collection in an API Fetch?

Now I have this:

```
body = { 'question': 'example_question', 'options' :  {
        'language': 'es', 
        "filter": 'collection_id:28283930205-ssf2-26-25252233-525233777'   #example collection_id    
    }}
post(URL, json = body, headers=headers)
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.